# Remove paratheses with text inside from dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How do you remove text in paratheses (paratheses included) from a df column?
For example:

| index | description |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Beef (Cow)) |
| 1 | Pork (Pig) |
| 2 | Hot Dog (Pig) |
| 3 | Chicken (Chicken) |
| 4 | Fish Sticks (Fish)) |

Should be:

| index | product |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Beef |
| 1 | Pork |
| 2 | Hot Dog |
| 3 | Chicken |
| 4 | Fish Sticks |

Answer (score 3):

Use `str.replace` with a Regular expression, like so:

```py
df["description"] = df["description"].str.replace(r'\s+\([^()]*\)', '')
```

- `\s+` matches any whitespace(s) before the parentheses
- `\(` matches `(` literally
- `[^()]*` matches any character that is not `(` or `)`, the `*` makes it repeat
- `\)` matches `)` literally

Comment: Given the OP's example, I think you can just use `df["description"].str.replace(r'\s+\(.*\)', '')`  since `.*` is greedy. But this wouldn't work if the strings can contain multiple "parentheses groups", i.e. "... (x) ... (y)" (which OP's example doesn't include). So I guess your solution is more general.

Answer (score 1):

One way using `pandas.Series.str.replace`:

```
df["description"] = df["description"].str.replace("\(+.+?\)+", "", regex=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   index   description
0      0         Beef 
1      1         Pork 
2      2      Hot Dog 
3      3      Chicken 
4      4  Fish Sticks
```